# Retrieving user profile image from Firebase but it is not displaying in ImageView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using this code to retrieve image but it is not showing in ImageView. I am beginner.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url

    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
    img.setImageURI(photoUrl);
    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in log?

Comment: Also check whether you `photoUrl` is null or not

Comment: @VaradMondkar log shows no error..will check photoUrl n report

Comment: Great take your time

Answer (score 0):

Since your are accessing `getPhotoUrl()` from `FirebaseAuth` instance that means you are trying to fetch image form remote location (from web).

`ImageView` does not support loading images from remote locations. Only resources or files on local file system can be loaded using `ImageView`.

So either you download the image yourself and then specify local path for `setImageURI` or use some best image loading or caching library -

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Any off these library could make your life easy.

Comment: While adding Glide or Picasso dependency? What error you are getting

Comment: dependency is resolved but in Picasso and glide (context) is red

Comment: so you are writing this code in `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url

        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
        Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(img);
        String uid = user.getUid();
        //Picasso.with(context).load(photoUrl).into(img);

    }

Comment: If you are writing it in `Activity` use `this` in place of `context`

Comment: If you are writing it in `Fragment` use `getContext()` in place of `context`

Comment: I wrote this..code is fine..but still not showing image in image view

Comment: Then check your logs once. Try debugging your code. If you need more help then paste your `ImageView` layout code and whole `Activity` in question.

Comment: i am pasting but it says cannot submit due to volume of spam

Comment: i just pasted what you said

Answer (score 0):

Java Activity

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;
    String post_key = null;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    private TextView txt,url;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userimg);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images");
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String name = sharedpreferences.getString("name", null);
        editor.commit();
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
        txt.setText(name);


        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url

            Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
            Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(img);
            String uid = user.getUid();
            //Picasso.with(context).load(photoUrl).into(img);

        }
    }


}
```

.XML

```
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/userimg"

                />
```

Firebase

```
Users
HzId4iQoBiZl4vcC2lcO7kHxFvx1
Username: 
"Humayun"
image: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-..."
name: 
"Being"
```